# Do questions asking for the origin of a word and the etymology of a word ask different things?

Tags: support, etymology

Is a question about the etymology of a word asking for its origin? Is a question about the origin of a word asking for its etymology?

As I understand it, the origin of a word could be the point from which it starts or sets out; for example, I could reply to a question saying that the word has been first used (in the context given from the question) in 1879.
In a question about the etymology of a word, I would expect that the answer reports from which word the asked word derives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word origin is a large subset of etymology, and on this site, they are usually used interchangeably. "Word origin" doesn't necessarily imply that you want to also know how the word has evolved over time, but that is also part of etymology. Again, I would personally consider them synonyms for the purposes of this site.