# What's the difference between "word origin" and "etymology"?

Tags: discussion, etymology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do questions asking for the origin of a word and the etymology of a word ask different things?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/do-questions-asking-for-the-origin-of-a-word-and-the-etymology-of-a-word-ask-diff)

I see in this boards two tags:

- [word-origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-origin)
- [etymology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)

What is the difference in meaning between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Online Dictionary has *word origin* meaning the original source of a word, and *etymology* to include that along with the history and historical changes of a word. So *word origin* is a subset of *etymology*.

See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/origin, http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/etymology